# Sql syntax error using python while generating id

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to generate a unique id for my data but I am getting syntax error here is my code

```
enter code here
 mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS donor_table("
                                   "ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL ,"
                                   "Prefix VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,"
                                   "Donor_id AS(Prefix+RIGHT(00000000+CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(11)),11))PERSISTED,"
                                   "First_Name VARCHAR(15),Last_Name VARCHAR(15),D_O_B DATE,Gender VARCHAR(10),Weight INT,"
                                   "Organization VARCHAR(25),Mail VARCHAR(25),Number CHAR(12),Blood_group VARCHAR(7),"
                                   "House VARCHAR(15),Street VARCHAR(15),Area VARCHAR(15),Date_Added DATE ,Status VARCHAR(12))")
```

here is the error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTITY(1,1)
> NOT NULL ,Prefix VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,Donor_id AS(Prefix+RIGHT(0000' at
> line 1

Comment: You've tagged MySQL, but this isn't MySQL

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have an `indentity` column - that's MS-SQL syntax. The equivilent in MySQL would be to use an `auto_increment` column:

```
ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: PERSISTED also need to change to the [mysql format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

Comment: @danblack indeed! Good catch!